# Magento 2 class not found error when overriding Magento_GroupedProduct model

Tags: php, class, overriding, magento2, extend

I have created a custom module in Magento 2.2.2 which extends the \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped class.

The module is successfully installed and enabled on the website, however, I am receiving a PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'ExtraMile\Catalog\Model\Grouped' not found in ../vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111.

My module folder structure is as follows:

**Image of module folder structure**

[image]

The **di.xml** file contains:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'ExtraMile_GroupedProduct',
__DIR__
);
```

The **module.xml** file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="ExtraMile_GroupedProduct" setup_version="1.0.2">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_GroupedProduct"/>
    </sequence>
  </module>
</config>
```

The **Grouped.php** file contains:

```
<?php
namespace ExtraMile\GroupedProduct\Model;

class Grouped extends \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped
{
  public function getAssociatedProducts($product)
  {
    if (!$product->hasData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts)) {
        $associatedProducts = [];

        $this->setSaleableStatus($product);

        $collection = $this->getAssociatedProductCollection(
            $product
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            ['name', 'price', 'special_price', 'special_from_date', 'special_to_date', 'tax_class_id']
        )->addFilterByRequiredOptions()->setPositionOrder()->addStoreFilter(
            $this->getStoreFilter($product)
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            'status',
            ['in' => $this->getStatusFilters($product)]
        );

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $associatedProducts[] = $item;
        }

        $product->setData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts, $associatedProducts);
    }
    return $product->getData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts);
  }
}
```

`bin/magento setup:di:compile` has been ran many times.

I have followed many tutorials such as: http://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/ and I cannot see why I am getting the error. Please can anyone advise what the issue is?

Comment: Well it has `Catalog` inserted into your namespace. This is probably `di` misconfiguration... why do you have PHP in that file, or is that a mistake in your question? It should be XML, shouldnt it? And is should specify the mapping/loading of models to substitute for the core ones.

Comment: Apologies, I copied the code for the registration.php instead of the di.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved:

I fixed this by moving the module folder from `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<module>` into `code/<vendor>/<module>`.

Running `bin/magento setup:di:compile` then removed the class not found error.